# Ruby Program Exits After Executing Code in Command Prompt

Tags: ruby, command-line, command-prompt, windows-console

Why does the program quit after being executed in the command line?

I saved the code below as a .rb file. When I run it, it goes through everything but it will not show me the resulting hash that I want to view. Instead, the program quits.

```
    def create_list
    print "What is the list name? "
    name=gets.chomp

    hash={"name"=>name,"items"=>Array.new}
    return hash
    end

    def add_list_item
    print "What is the item called? "
    item_name=gets.chomp

    print "How much? "
    quantity=gets.chomp.to_i

    hash={"name"=>item_name, "quantity"=>quantity}
    return hash
    end


   def print_separator(character="-")
    puts character *80

    end


   def print_list(list)
     puts "List: #{list['name']}"
     print_separator()

   list["items"].each do |item|
   puts "\tItem: " + item['name'] + "\t\t\t" +
   "Quantity: " + item['quantity'].to_s

   end
    print_separator()

    end

   list=create_list()
   list['items'].push(add_list_item())
   list['items'].push(add_list_item())

   puts "Here is your list: \n"
   print_list(list)
```

Comment: Where? Please let me know where it is and whether that is causing my problem

Comment: Added this at the end and the program did not exit and I was able to see the list:
    puts "Press RETURN when you're done."
    gets

Comment: This indentation is pure anarchy. If you organized your code better and got things properly indented the mistakes would be far more obvious.

Comment: Are you running this script by double clicking on it in Explorer? If so, it's creating a new console. When the script exits the console has no attached processes and also exits. If you run the script from CMD, it should inherit CMD's console instead of creating a new one. Then when the script exits CMD will resume as the console foreground process.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your code, i recommend when ever you face problems of this kind to run the command ruby -wc file_name.rb , this is what it printed out:

`list.rb:22: warning: *' after local variable or literal is interpreted as binary operator`

`list.rb:22: warning: even though it seems like argument prefix`

`list.rb:24: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'def' at 21`

`list.rb:38: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'def' at 27`

`Syntax OK`

So after fixing the indentations the next thing you have to fix is the method print_separator:

```
def print_separator(character="-")
     puts character *80
end
```

Change it to:

```
def print_separator()
    80.times do |n|
      print "-"
    end
    puts
end
```

Here also is a working version of the same code:

```rb
def create_list
  print "What is the list name? "
  name=gets.chomp

  hash={"name"=>name,"items"=>Array.new}
  return hash
end

def add_list_item
  print "What is the item called? "
  item_name=gets.chomp

  print "How much? "
  quantity=gets.chomp.to_i

  hash={"name"=>item_name, "quantity"=>quantity}
  return hash
end


def print_separator()
    80.times do |n|
       print "-"
    end
    puts
end


def print_list(list)
  puts "List: #{list['name']}"
  print_separator()

  list["items"].each do |item|
    puts "\tItem: " + item['name'] + "\t\t\t" +
    "Quantity: " + item['quantity'].to_s
  end
  print_separator()
end

list=create_list()
list['items'].push(add_list_item())
list['items'].push(add_list_item())

puts "Here is your list: \n"
print_list(list)
```

Output:

`What is the list name? My list`
`What is the item called? apple`
`How much? 2`
`What is the item called? orange`
`How much? 2`
`Here is your list:`
`List: My list`
`--------------------------------------------------------------------------------`
`Item: apple                Quantity: 2`
`Item: orange           Quantity: 2`
`--------------------------------------------------------------------------------`